# Add string into a list and remove the text in the search bar of a SearchInput / textinput

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

Lets say I have a searchInput from shinyWidgets or regular textinput from Shiny on my app.

I want the user to able to write something, press enter - the code adds that into a list.
Such that *search_1* **ENTER**, *search_2* **ENTER**, *search_3* **ENTER**

That searchinput UI shall be reset everytime enter is hit.

Output needs to be "search_1, search_2, search_3"

I have workaround for now, with searchInput splits the input text with ", " so the user needs to type "search_1, search_2, search_3" themselves, which is not optimal for the use.

Hope could this be done? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a reactive value `search_text` storing all inputs:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyWidgets)

ui <- fluidPage(
  searchInput("search"),
  textOutput("text")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  # store all entered search terms
  search_text <- reactiveVal(value = "")
  
  observeEvent(
    eventExpr = input$search,
    handlerExpr = {
      # add current search term
      search_text() %>%
        paste0(input$search, ", ") %>%
        search_text()
      
      # reset input text
      updateSearchInput(session, "search", value = "")
    }
  )
  
  output$text <- renderText(search_text())
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image]